# if this selected, var equals this value

Tags: jquery, html, forms, select

I really have to start working on my javascript skills. I'm trying to, what I thought would be a simple task with jquery, set a certain value to a variable depending on the `option` that is chosen.

```
<select>
<option>Choose size</option>
<option id="size1">1</option>
<option id="size2">2</option>
<option id="size3">3</option>
<option id="size4">4</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="showPrice"/>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var thisPrice;

$('#size1').each(function(){
    if(this.selected)
        thisPrice = 2;
        });
    $('#size2').each(function(){
    if(this.selected)
        thisPrice = 4;
        });

$('#size3').each(function(){
    if(this.selected)
        thisPrice = 5;
        });

$('#size4').each(function(){
    if(this.selected)
        thisPrice = 6;
        });


    $('#showPrice').val(thisPrice);
```

[Link to my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamjosan/8ULeH/)

**How can I get this to work?**

Comment: Use option value and get the select val. simple

Comment: This is a simple thing and I would recommend avoiding event handers as in many of the answers if all you need is to get the value in code at some other time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `.each()`s or the `id`s on your elements. Basically, you need to bind an event handler to listen for changes to the `select`, and react. I would do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/dGHak/

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var thisPrice = '';

    switch (this.value) {
        case '1':
            thisPrice = 2;
            break;

        case '2':
            thisPrice = 4;
            break;

        case '3':
            thisPrice = 5;
            break;

        case '4':
            thisPrice = 6;
            break;
    }

    $('#showPrice').val(thisPrice);
});
```

Here's another option using `data-` attributes:

http://jsfiddle.net/9fvZq/

```
<select>
    <option>Choose size</option>
    <option data-price="2">1</option>
    <option data-price="4">2</option>
    <option data-price="5">3</option>
    <option data-price="6">4</option>
</select>
```

---

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    $('#showPrice').val($(this).find('option:selected').data('price'));
});
```

Comment: I didn't even know about `data-price`. I like that a lot. The less code the better.

Comment: That's a `data-` attribute. You can make any you want.. `data-id`, `data-pickle`, `data-orange`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try this on for size:

```
    <select>
        <option>Choose size</option>
        <option id="size1" value="2">1</option>
        <option id="size2" value="4">2</option>
        <option id="size3" value="5">3</option>
        <option id="size4" value="6">4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="showPrice"/>
```

put the values in the options, then you can use this simple query

```
    var changed = function(e){
       $("#showPrice").val(e.target.value);
    }
    $('select').on('change', changed);
```

fiddle me timbers http://jsfiddle.net/8ULeH/7/

Comment: No need for `.attr()`, `.val()` is the proper method for setting the element's `value` property. You also forgot to declare the `changed` variable which implicitly makes it a global, you should declare it or use an anonymous function. http://jsfiddle.net/8ULeH/5/

Answer (score 1):

You should just set an id for the select, use value instead of id in the options and use:

```
var val = $('#theID').val();
```

Comment: jQuery objects don't have a `value` property.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté  - thanx. I don't use jquery much. I'd just do it in JS ;)

Comment: Yeah, `.val` is a method so I've fixed it for you. `$('#theID')[0].value` would work too.

Answer (score 0):

Add an [event listener](http://api.jquery.com/change/) to the `select` element that fires when it changes:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
    var thisPrice;

    $('#size1').each(function () {
        if (this.selected) thisPrice = 2;
    });
    $('#size2').each(function () {
        if (this.selected) thisPrice = 4;
    });

    $('#size3').each(function () {
        if (this.selected) thisPrice = 5;
    });

    $('#size4').each(function () {
        if (this.selected) thisPrice = 6;
    });


    $('#showPrice').val(thisPrice);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8ULeH/1/

We can actually clean this up further with a case statement:

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
  // Gets the id of the selected option
  var theId = this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].id;
  switch (theId) {
    case 'size1':
        $('#showPrice').val(2);
        break;
    case 'size2':
        $('#showPrice').val(4);
        break;
    case 'size3':
        $('#showPrice').val(5);
        break;
    case 'size4':
        $('#showPrice').val(6);
        break;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for editing the post with the link attached. I really need to start doing more reading on this java stuff.So pretty much I need an event followed by a function, right?

Comment: Yep, I just edited in an alternate way to do it that's a bit faster.  If I answered your question, don't forget to upvote and accept!

Comment: You answered my question and I like the case method too. I was also thinking of doing an if elseif loop but wasn't sure how to go about that. I'll accept your answer once SO lets me. I guess you have to wait 7 minutes before you can accept an answer.